# Location of USB header files for Include

Tags: usb, compiling, libraries, c

I'm working on porting a Windows application to Ubuntu 14.04. The application is a host-side GUI for a USB device that uses the generic HID interface. I need to Include the header files for the default USB drivers embedded with the Ubuntu 14 installation but have not been able to locate where those headers can be found.

Those files may be named something like `libusb.h` or maybe `usb.h`. Can anyone offer a suggestion where to look?

I am a new user to Linux so please keep your responses exact or I may get lost. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

The file `libusb.h` is in package `libusb-1.0-0-dev`:

```
libusb-1.0-0-dev: /usr/include/libusb-1.0/libusb.h
```

while `usb.h` is provided by `libusb-dev`:

```
libusb-dev: /usr/include/usb.h
```

Without more details about your application it's hard to know which is required.

Comment: HI and thanks for the response. My installed system is Ubuntu version 14.04 LTS. Under the /usr/include/ path name I do not see libusb-1.0    Is it possible that the folder is hidden? And if so, how would I make it visible?

Comment: No it should not be hidden - did you actually confirm that the package is installed (either from the Software Center, or by running `sudo apt-get install libusb-1.0-0-dev` from a terminal?)